# Following-Sibling Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table that has the same 2 buttons on each row (**Start, Cancel**).
I am trying to click the **'Start'** button on the second row called **'Free Toys'**. There are 2 buttons that are right next to each other: 1: Cancel 2: Start.

How can I click the **'Start'** button for **Free Toys** which is located on the second row?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'FreeToys')]//following-sibling::button[@class='btn btn-success btn-sm']").click()
```

HTML CODE for entire ROW

```
<tr ng-repeat="toyService in theServices" ng-class="{'text-muted': toyService.notFound}" class="ng-scope"> 
        <td style="text-align:center">
         <toy-up-down state="toyService.state" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down text-danger" title="Unknown" aria- hidden="true"></span></toy-up-down></td> 
   <td class="ng-binding">Free Toys</td> 
   <td class="ng-binding">Come get free toys</td> 
   <td class="toy-service-button-panel text-right">
          <button type="CANCEL" ui-sref="toyService.detail({id:toyService.id})" 
                 class="btn btn-info btn-sm toy-service-button-margin"info btn-sm toy-service-button-margin"                   
           ==The button I am trying to click is located below===
         <button type="START" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (toyService.packageName)" 
                 ng-show="toyService.state !== 'Operational'" ng-disabledng-click="theStartClick
                  ="toyService.notFound" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false"> 
       </span> </button> 
       </td> </tr>
```

Comment: Try this - //td[contains(text(), 'FreeToys')]//following-sibling::td[@class='toy-service-button-panel text-right']/button[@class='btn btn-success btn-sm'].... button is not the following sibling td is...

Comment: I get an error that says "Unsupported Characters in input"

Comment: Try xpath in the browser and check if it works...

Comment: the xpath works

Comment: then you got a python problem...